# Converting a hash to array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm fairly new to ruby and I've got a hash that looks like so:

```
{ ["key1", "key2"] => 5, ["key1", "key3"] => 2, ... }
```

and I would like to convert it to an array that looks something like

```
[ ["key1", "key2", 5], ["key1", "key3", 2] ... ]
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply:

```
hash.collect{|k, v| k << v}
```

Of if you need the original hash unchanged:

```
hash.collect{|k, v| k + [v]}
```

Comment: Your first one (or this version of it `map { |k, v| k + [v] }`) didn't mangle the original Hash's keys.

Comment: nit-picking: variable naming is *very* important. If you write `k` you're saying "singular/single-item". If write `ks` you are saying "plural/collection".

Answer (score 2):

Another way could be:

```
hash.map(&:flatten)
# => [["key1", "key2", 5], ["key1", "key3", 2]]
```

Answer (score -1):

to_a does exactly that.

```
{ ["key1", "key2"] => 5, ["key1", "key3"] => 2}.to_a
```

Comment: No, look at the desired output: `[ ["key1", "key2", 5], ["key1", "key3", 2] ... ]`.